# Weekends color css rule doesn't work in timeline view

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I wonder if css rule for weekends `.fc-sat, .fc-sun {background-color: red !important;}` works in timeline v.5. I tried to insert it in main.css but had no result.
Thank you.

I actually found the answer myself. In version 5, weekend css rule looks like that:

```
.fc-day-sun {
    background-color: red;
}
```

However, I've found a bug there. Using the following css rule

```
.fc-day-sat {
    background-color: red;
}
```

changes not only day slot background but also background of timeline slot frame for August, November and May. [background-color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxUl8.png)

Comment: There's not enough context here for us to help you. You'd need to add more information. Please see the How To Ask guide in the help section if you need assistance on how to ask a good quality question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its for the specificity, try to looking for other class with the same name and see if there is another !important that its causing trouble, if there's another try to put more specificity.

Use !important cause a lot of problems, and its a bad practice.

This is a post that talk about that: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

If you find the other !important try to delete it, but if you can use !important in that case and use the specificity.